# Why does the direct input do not work in harbor？

Tags: docker, harbor

I use Docker login `--username=xx --password=xx 192.168.0.92:7082`
but it does not work!

```
Error response from daemon: Get http://192.168.0.92:7082/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required
```

And I use Docker login `192.168.0.92:7082` or docker login `--username=xx 192.168.0.92:7082`.  I can login the harbor，I do not know why？
Do you have to use docker login and then input the username then input password？ Why does the direct input not work？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taday, I found the answer！Harbor logon is no problem！The cause of the problem is I used an unconventional password！eg: 1q2w#E$R, $ is a special symbol！So i cannot login the harbor！